# Recorrer un objeto

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
  [{
          "servidor": "localhost",
          "usuario": "root",
          "password": "1234",
          "basededatos": "db_2019"
        },
        {
          "servidor": "192.168.1.25",
          "usuario": "root",
          "password": "12345",
          "basededatos": "db_2018"
        }]
```

En la consola aparece de esta forma:

```
0: {…}
​​basededatos: "db_2019"
​​password: "1234"
​​servidor: "localhost"
​​usuario: "root"
​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​1: {…}
​​​​basededatos: "db_2018"
​​password: "12345"
​​servidor: "192.168.1.25"
​​usuario: "root"
```

---

como recorrer el "0: {}" ? o los de "1:{}" 
ej:

```
 <input type="text" id="servidor" *ngFor="let db_json of dbjson" [value]="db_json.servidor" [(ngModel)]="db_json.servidor">
​​
```

quiero obtener los datos del "0: {...}
basededatos: "db_2019"
​​password: "1234"
​​servidor: "localhost"
​​usuario: "root""

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO en español, te aconsejo que completes el [tour] para conocer mejor el sitio y te familiarices con lo que es un [mcve] y cómo hacer buenas preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

El ngFor de angular es similar a un bucle `for ... of ...` estándar de Javascript:

```
for (let db_json of dbjson) {

}
```

Por tanto la variable db_json es local, no existe una vez se ha completado el bucle. Debes hacer que el modelo apunte a un atributo del componente. Puedes probar con:

```
<input type="text" id="servidor" *ngFor="let db_json of dbjson;let i = index" 
  [value]="db_json.servidor" [(ngModel)]="dbjson[i].servidor">
```